# #sequelize_validation , validation field on model is base on the pre field

Tags: sequelize.js

I want field 2 allownull when field 1 have value is true or false, (value of field 2 base on field 1) on model of sequelize. please help

can run completely and no error synxtax . I try them but con not run and have more error same as image.
Can you help me for the truth solution and syntax